Unable to download PDF file in the real device in flutter
I want to download the pdf on the click of a button in the real device which is connected to the flutter project using the usb cable but unable to do so. I have used Dio package of flutter and have also tried other many packages of flutter/ dart but that didn't work for me.
Here's what I have tried :-
Firstly, I have extracted the data from the pdf url , then i have used the package called device_info_plugin to get the android info , once get the android info then seeking for the permission for the storage of pdf file. After getting the permission , figured the directory in which i want the file to be stored, then in order to download the file in the real device directory i used the Dio package of flutter, but it also didn't work for me still I am getting the path but not downloading the pdf file in the device. Here's the code for the above explaination:-
 final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(widget.documentUrl));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
      final AndroidDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;

      if (info.version.sdkInt < 33) {
        var status = await Permission.storage.status;

        if (status.isDenied ||
            status.isRestricted ||
            status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
          status = await Permission.storage.request();
        }

        if (!status.isGranted) {
          if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
            _showSettingsDialog();
          } else {
            _showPermissionDeniedDialog();
          }
          throw Exception('Storage permission not granted');
        }
      }

      // final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectories(
      //         type: StorageDirectory.downloads))
      //     ?.first;
      // final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      Directory directory;
      if (info.version.sdkInt >= 30) {
        directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectories(
                    type: StorageDirectory.downloads))
                ?.first ??
            await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      } else {
        directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      }

      if (!await directory.exists()) {
        throw Exception('Could not access external storage');
      }
      // directory = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Download");
      // if (!await directory.exists())
      //   directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

      if (directory == null) {
        throw Exception('Could not access external storage');
      }

      final path = '${directory.path}/downloaded.pdf';
      final file = File(path);
      final resp = await Dio().get(widget.documentUrl,
          options: Options(
            responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
            followRedirects: false,
          ));
      final raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);

      raf.writeFromSync(resp.data);
      await raf.close();

      // await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

      setState(() {
        _pdfPath = path;
      });
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });

      // setState(() {
      //   _isLoading = false;
      // });
      // return file;
      print('PDF downloaded to: $_pdfPath');
      return file;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load PDF');
    }
  }

Here's what I am expecting :-
I am expecting , on a click/taping of a button I want to download the pdf url in a real device from which i am using the mobile app in the flutter project
